# Issue for optimizing mysql index

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have a mysql table with approximatively 1.5 million lines.
This table contains a column called `companies (integer)` which contains few different values (3 or 4) and another column called `orders (varchar)` which contain a lot of different values (but some identical).

I created an multi-column index (type INDEX) with columns `companies` and `orders`.

I have a simple query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE companies = 1 AND orders = '344A7884'
```

There is no execution time difference (around 4 secondes) when I execute this query with the index implemented or without.

The only way I found to get an execution time of around 1 seconde is to create an index only on "orders" and run the following transformed query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE orders = 34467884) RQ1 WHERE companies = 1
```

That seems not to be very proper.
Can someone explain me this strange behavior and suggest a better way to optimize the index?

Comment: `Explain` statement results would be helpful

Comment: It would be nice if you could post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1`. It would be critical to post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ....`.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to help you. Please read this article about [asking good questions about SQL](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/). Please pay special attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: is orders numeric or string? in your second SQL you manage it as a numeric field...

Comment: Agree that I haven't provided enough information. I tried to make the question clearer by presenting it in a simple way. But I understand It was a bad idea...

Comment: Anyway, I used "explain" and I saw that the good index was used. I delete it and recreate it and then execution time is good. Unfortunately I'm not able to compare the two index (before and after creation) so I assume I made an error when I created the index for the first time.... I'll check again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an indexed column is a `VARCHAR` then do *not* test it against a number without quotes.  For example, if `companies` is `VARCHAR(99)`,

```
companies = 1  -- will scan the entire table (slow)
companies = '1'  -- can use the index (fast)
```

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

If `companies` is, say, `INT` and `orders` is a `VARCHAR`, then

```
WHERE companies = 1 AND orders = '344A7884'
```

would work very fast with *either* of these:

```
INDEX(companies, orders)
INDEX(orders, companies)
```

Comment: However, why if we query an integer on a varchar field mysql don't use the index? It seems to be strange for me as I would expect that mysql cast automaticaly the input to the expected type. I don't see the interest to not do so.

Comment: @www.diazis.com - In it's infinite wisdom, MySQL (or may be the ANSI standard) decided that the literal dominates, and must convert the column to numeric.  But, the column is assuming that it will be compared against strings, hence it is ill-prepared for comparing against numbers.

Comment: To further confuse things, if you have `'344A7884'` in the `orders` column, you will find that `orders = 344` succeeds!  This is because of the way it converts strings to numbers.  And there are anomolies like `'2`' > `'10'` because of the way strings compare.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly a mistake when creating the index the first time. Will test again and see if this issue appear again.
Thanks for the comments.